# HTML5 / Canvas "Glass" Circle

Tags: html, canvas

I need to render a simple chart and I want the points to be glassy looking circles/orbs in the chart area.  I can find tons of examples of drawing these with Photoshop, but I don't want to use stock images; I'd prefer to draw them in my HTML5 canvas.  I am no artist, though!

There are many HTML5 canvas questions, but I don't see anything that leads me to this solution.

A point in the right direction would be most appreciated.

Comment: Can you link to the photoshop examples? If I were doing this I'd probably just work through those, but do the steps in canvas instead.

Comment: Unless the "glass" images need to change in some way, why bother making canvas do the heavy lifting. Just use a PNG.

Comment: @j08691 - Well, my original plan was to allow the user to pick the colors they want, but perhaps that's not such a good idea and I should just build a variety of .PNGs to reference.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @david, your comment seems so obvious. I'm embarrassed to say that it never occurred to me.  I truly never program graphics, so that's the excuse I'm going to go with.  I may do just that, as an exercise, but will likely go with the other folks' suggestion of building .PNGs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you have to do is create one or more radial gradients to fit the properties of the glassy object that you want. It's easy to do!

Just one gradient:

```
// Create some gradient
var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(105, 105, 20, 120, 120, 50);
gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(250,250,255,0)');
gradient.addColorStop(0.75, 'rgba(230,250,255,1.0)');
gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,0,255,0)');

// draw the gradient (note that we dont bother drawing a circle, this is more efficient and less work!)
// but make sure it covers the entire gradient
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);​
```

Can make this:

[image]

Live example:

http://jsfiddle.net/GTbjk/

Maybe you want to reign in that fuzzy edge:

```
gradient.addColorStop(0.8, 'rgba(0,0,255,0)');
gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,0,255,0)');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GTbjk/1/

I'm not going to make one to your specification, since you didn't provide one and thats not what we're here for anyway. Making these will almost exclusively be the work of well-placed radial gradients, so go experiment!

As j08691 points out this is a really inefficent way of making these unless you want them to be dynamic or scalable, you are better off just making images and use `ctx.drawImage`

Comment: Simon, This is very visually appealing.  I really need to get a book on computer graphics because you made this look so nice with so little code.  As I mentioned in my comment above, my original plan was to allow flexibility in color selection, but maybe that's not necessary and I should just build a collection of 20 or so .PNG files and reference those.  Thanks again, Simon!