# Drawing fancy Circle on canvas has weird effect

Tags: javascript, geometry, html5-canvas, drawing

I'm trying to draw a circle on a canvas and it's generating as follows:

[image: Circle with weird effect], and zoomed:  [image]

I'm not sure why this is happening, though I've seen the effect before and I suspect it's something to do with partial pixels (though afaict I'm not doing that). A working example can be seen at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/metalskin/gcpvv/2/).

To summarise the code, I'm using a function to draw the circle. I draw both the inside and outside edge progressively inwards, adjusting the alpha as I go. The code can be seen below:

```
function drawCircle(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, antiClockwise, lineWidth, r, g, b, a) {
    c.beginPath(); 

    var w = Math.abs(lineWidth / 2);

    var alphaFactor = a / w;
    var alpha = alphaFactor;

    var outer = radius + w;
    var inner = radius - w;

    // draw centre line
    c.lineWidth = 1;
    c.strokeStyle = 'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ',' + a + ')';
    c.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, true); 
    c.stroke();

    for(i = 0; i < w; i++, inner++, outer--, alpha += alphaFactor) {
        // draw inner
        c.beginPath(); 
        c.strokeStyle = 'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ',' + alpha + ')';
        c.arc(x, y, inner, startAngle, endAngle, true); 
        c.stroke();

        // draw outer
        c.beginPath(); 
        c.arc(x, y, outer, startAngle, endAngle, true); 
        c.stroke();
    }
};
```

I believe that I can use a radial gradient to solve this problem (which I presume will be faster, depending on the width of the line), however I would like to understand why the affect shown above occurs.

Comment: [moire pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by not drawing individual lines and just drawing one line with a radial gradient that recreated the effect I am looking for:

[image]

This appears (afaict) to be a lot more efficient as it's only using one fill, instead of multiple strokes.

The solution can be seen at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/metalskin/MYedA/), while the code is quite small:

```
$(function () {
  draw(document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'));

  function draw(ctx) {
    var radgrad = ctx.createRadialGradient(60, 60, 0, 60, 60, 60);
    radgrad.addColorStop(0.8, 'rgba(255,0,0,0)');
    radgrad.addColorStop(0.85, 'rgba(255,0,0,.6)');
    radgrad.addColorStop(0.9, 'rgba(255,0,0,1)');
    radgrad.addColorStop(0.95, 'rgba(255,0,0,.6)');
    radgrad.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(255,0,0,0)');

    ctx.fillStyle = radgrad;
    ctx.arc(60, 60, 60, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    ctx.fill();
  }
});
```

I derived my solution from the solution to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9743575/1125784).

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is due to anti-aliasing/rounding effects of non-straight lines (which a circle contains a lot). Especially, with a (very) small line width. My guess is, that this results in partially overlapping circle lines, lines that are partially next to each other, and maybe even lines that are leaving a gap at some places...

The problem seems to be fixed with an increased line width:

```
c.lineWidth = 1.4;
```

See the updated [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/veger/gcpvv/3/).

Comment: Sorry Veger but that doesn't appear to work for me. I am still seeing the strange (moire pattern?) artefacts in your JSFiddle.

Comment: Did you try to increase the `lineWidth` some more?